# SQL bug in Microsoft R

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

**Edit to the below question: I fixed the problem by setting blocksperread = 20, which is the same number of blocks in my XDF file, but I don't know why this should work! :)**

I have been experiencing the following problem writing an XDF file to a table on SQL Server. My XDF file has 9725094 rows, 148 variables, and 20 blocks. I have stored its filename as 'testset'.

I declare a new sqlTable as 'dbo.table1', and then write:

sqloutput <- RxSqlServerData(connectionString = sqlConnString, table = sqlTable),

where sqlConnString has the server properties, and it is confirmed that RServer 9.1 is installed on here.

I then do the datastep:

rxDataStep(inData = testset, outFile = sqloutput, overwrite = T), when running I get:

```
  Total Rows written: 100000, Total time: 13.878
Total Rows written: 200000, Total time: 24.47
Total Rows written: 300000, Total time: 34.851
Total Rows written: 400000, Total time: 45.534
Total Rows written: 500000, Total time: 60.11
Rows Read: 500000, Total Rows Processed: 500000, Total Chunk Time: 64.348 seconds
Total Rows written: 100000, Total time: 10.967
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  no message recieved from pipe
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  Write error: expected 8 got 
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  Write error: expected 8 got
```

It writes the "first chunk" fine, as can be confirmed from querying the server through SSMS, but, when going on to the second chunk, it fails, and for that matter all of the RServer functions fail, I have to restart my R session.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using R Server or R Client?

Comment: Hi R-Server, of course :)

Comment: Hi @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli, quick question - where are you executing this from; a separate machine, or on the SQL Server box you write to? Also what are you using to execute; RStudio, Visual Studio, `sp_execute_external_script` from inside SQL Server? As a side noteI have come across this `Write error: expected 8 got ` when I fill up a disk on my local machine, or are about to run out of memory. It is strange though that it seems that Rserver seems to fail ...

Comment: Hi @NielsBerglund I tried both instances: I tried writing to a SQL Server box that is separate from the box I am on, and on the same one, both cases fail in exactly the same way. I have also tried RStudio and Visual Studio, and both fails happen. The entire R session crashes, and I have to restart R to get even basic functions to work!